# Python: find a x,y coordinate for a given point B using the distance from the point A (x0, y0) and the angle

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, trigonometry, angle

Is there a function already implemented in Python to find the X, Y of a point B from a point A (x0, Y0) using a given angle expressed in degrees (°)?

```
from math import cos, sin

def point_position(x0, y0, dist, theta):
    return dist*sin(theta), dist*cos(theta)
```

where `x0` = x coordinate of point A, `y0` = y coordinate of point A, `dist` = distance between A and B, `theta` = angle (°) of the point B respect the North (0°) measured by a compass

Comment: you need to add x0 and y0 to your returning values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need a function that [converts degrees to radians](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#math.radians). Then your function simply becomes:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians, pi
def point_pos(x0, y0, d, theta):
    theta_rad = pi/2 - radians(theta)
    return x0 + d*cos(theta_rad), y0 + d*sin(theta_rad)
```

(as you can see you mixed up sine and cosine in your original function)

(also note the linear angle transformation because angles on compass are clockwise and mathematical angles are counter-clockwise. Also there is an offset between the respective zeroes)

You can also use [complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cmath.html) to represent points, which is somewhat nicer than a tuple of coordinates (although a dedicated `Point` class would be even more appropriate):

```
import cmath
def point_pos(p, d, theta):
    return p + cmath.rect(d, pi/2-radians(theta))
```

Comment: maybe use `math.radians` instead of rewriting a function for it?

Comment: thanks @niklas you are right. only change d in dist in the point_pos formula and the example is perfect!

Comment: @M4rtini Good point. I also forgot a simple translation of the angle because OP's angles are weird.

Comment: Thanks @M4rtini and niklas suppose you have a center coordinate of x0 =0 and y0 = 0, the distance AB = 5 and the angle of B is 90°. The coordinate need to be x0= 5, y0= 0. Using point_pos(0, 0, 5, 90) i get xb = -3.5355339059327373 and yb = 3.5355339059327378

Comment: @Gianni I get (5,0). Maybe you're using an old revision of my code, I used `pi/4` instead of `pi/2`

Comment: @NiklasB. corerct pu in pi :)

Comment: I was getting incorrect results with how the theta conversion was done. I used theta_rad = theta*(pi/180)